# How to continuously make image rotate

Tags: css, css-transitions

i have logo that i want to continuously rotate when hovered. How to achieve this? is it doable with only css3 or we need javascript help? and one more thing, when those logo unhovered it just stop without finishing rotation. How can we tell css to finish rotate even logo is unhovered.

my current css is :

```
header .logo:hover img{ 
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 1.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 1.2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 1.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(720deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(720deg);
    transform: rotateY(720deg); 
    filter: progid : DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage ( rotation = 2 )
}
```

Comment: have you looked at animation-timing-function ?

Comment: i just find any other question after i write this question. haha. yes i find it. than next question, how to tell animation to continue until finishing rotation when logo is unhovered.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use keyframe animations for this.

Demo (webkit): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWFEv/)

Code:

```
.one:hover {
    -webkit-animation: all 1.2s linear infinite;


}

@-webkit-keyframes all
{

0%   {-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);}
100% {-webkit-transform: rotateY(720deg);}

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. Maybe you can find some info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/

Comment: I actually don't think it's possible now when I come to think about it. When you hover out the animation "breaks" and the element jumps back to it's original state. But you might be able to add a transition to the original state that kicks in when the animation stops ...

Answer (score -1):

try with css3 animation:

```
-webkit-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
-o-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
```